# config module not called

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router

I use `ui-router` but `ui-router` can't find one of my state: `Could not resolve 'main.tabs' from state 'main'`. I found out that the `config` of the `tabs` module is not called, so `main.tabs` is not registered.

The initial state: `$urlRouterProvider.otherwise('/main/dashboard');`

The navigation to `main.tabs` is done with `<a ui-sref="main.tabs" class="item" ng-click="toggleMenu()">Tabs</a>`

index.html

```
<script src="app/main/main.js"></script>
<script src="app/tabs/tabs.js"></script>
<script src="app/dashboard/dashboard.js"></script>
<script src="app/app.js"></script>
```

main.js

```
var main = angular.module('main', []);

main.config(function ($stateProvider) {
    $stateProvider
        .state('main', {
            url: "/main",
            abstract: true,
            templateUrl: "./app/main/main.html"
        });
});
```

tabs.js

```
var tabs = angular.module('tabs', ['main']);

tabs.config(function ($stateProvider) {
    $stateProvider
        .state('main.tabs', {
            url: '/tabs',
            views: {
                'main': {
                    templateUrl: './app/tabs/tabs.html',
                    controller: 'TabsCtrl'
                }
            }
        });
    // This is not called, I don't see the trace in the logs
    console.log($stateProvider);
});
```

dashboard.js

```
var dashboard = angular.module('dashboard', ['models.dashboards', 'main']);

dashboard.config(function ($stateProvider) {
    $stateProvider
        .state('main.dashboard', {
            url: "/dashboard",
            views: {
                'main': {
                    resolve: {
                        'dashboard': ['DashboardService', function (DashboardService) {
                            return DashboardService.getInstance();
                        }]
                    },
                    templateUrl: "./app/dashboard/dashboard.html",
                    controller: 'DashboardCtrl'
                }
            }
        });
    console.log($stateProvider);
});
```

Edit: `ui.router` is included

app.js (ionic is bundled with ui-router)

```
angular.module('starter', ['ionic', 'restangular', 'dashboard', 'ngCordova', 'LocalStorageModule', 'services.auth'])
```

From the ionic source:

```
var IonicModule = angular.module('ionic', ['ngAnimate', 'ngSanitize', 'ui.router']),
```

`ng-app` directive from index.html

```
<body ng-app="starter">
<ion-nav-view></ion-nav-view>
</body>
```

Comment: Show us your `ng-app` directive in the html file.

Comment: Looks like you are missing the ui router dependency in your modules. The dependency is ui.route.

Comment: ui.router is bundled with ionic, so the dependency is included. See edit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your app is the `starter` module. `starter` depends on `dashboard`. `dashboard` depends on `main`. None of those modules depend on `tabs`. So the `tabs` module is not loaded.